# grep lines that appear partly in one file to another

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I have a file #1 that has lines as such:

`SSJ4_00089026.dpx
SSJ4_00089134.dpx
SSJ4_00090253.dpx
SSJ4_00090267.dpx
SSJ4_00090379.dpx
SSJ4_00090392.dpx
SSJ4_00090492.dpx
SSJ4_00094320.dpx`

and another file #2 that has lines as such:

`693d092aba91a6acd2b8d73903fe4f78  SSJ4_00089026.dpx
0333b53c486de6a7214c05fd583f9745  SSJ4_00089134.dpx
fdc713709251e0538a84549355627e65  SSJ4_00090253.dpx
a8766ba5d6e1ee854bf7db10c05c7e55  SSJ4_00090267.dpx
733f6564ca442974555a76b91d506cff  SSJ4_00090379.dpx
f6154ddf1d7ae7c8076f08c25c9fe2c3  SSJ4_00094320.dpx`

All of the lines in #1 are in #2, but they don't have the hash. 
Not all of the lines in #2 are in #1.

I want to pull all the lines that are #1 from #2 including the hash and put them into a new file, #3. So that #3 would look like:

`ccfd092aba91a6acd2b8d73903fe4f78  SSJ4_00089026.dpx
056nb53c486de6a7214c05fd583f9745  SSJ4_00089134.dpx
45g313709251e0538a84549355627e65  SSJ4_00090253.dpx`

etc

I'm thinking some command with grep such as 
`grep -v -f -i file#1 file#2 >> file#3` or maybe `awk`

Comment: Your example data makes no sense. None of the patterns in output file #3 are part of #2

Comment: You can do it using join https://www.computerhope.com/unix/ujoin.htm

Comment: Your input has fields. grep does not support operating on fields. therefore you should not use grep on your input. awk, on the other hand, does support operating on fields.

Comment: @EdMorton that is what I thought as well, but both of the given answers using grep worked.

Comment: @hek2mgl ok. I fixed that.

Comment: @Bleakley no, they don't, you just haven't come across the input cases where they fail yet. Maybe you'll get lucky though and those cases won't ever occur in your real data. Not sure why you'd want to take that chance rather than just using the robust awk approach of course...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
grep -iFf file1 file2 > file
```

you need to tell `grep` that it is in `fgrep` mode with the `-F` option, then the `-f` specifies what file to read from.

Note that I have changed your `>>` redirect (append) to `>` (create). 
You'll trip yourself up in testing using `>>`, as your first tests will always appear at the top of the file, and if you're rushing you won't think it is working. Use `>` for development and if you really need append mode, then add it after you are certain you basic cmd is working as required.

Finally, I'd use the `-i` (ignore case) option sparingly. If you  really need to match lower case versions of your target strings, better to include those in your `file1`, so your process is self documenting.

IHTH

Answer (score 4):

NOTE: It was pointed out in the comments correctly that `grep` will have problems if you stick to having fields.

do this `grep -Fwf file2 file1 > out` . 
,or use

`awk 'NR==FNR{pats[$0]; next} $2 in pats' File2 File1`

Comment: Darn I want to upvote the awk script but don't want anything thinking they should use the grep script. Guess I'll just leave this comment...

Answer (score 1):

```
cat file1 | xargs -I@ -n1 grep @ file2 | tee file3
```

Print file1. Using xargs make each line of file 1 the pattern to grep call. Write the output to file3

Input file1:

```
SSJ4_00086400.dpx
SSJ4_00086403.dpx
```

Input file2:

```
693d092aba91a6acd2b8d73903fe4f78  SSJ4_00086400.dpx
0333b53c486de6a7214c05fd583f9745  SSJ4_00086401.dpx
fdc713709251e0538a84549355627e65  SSJ4_00086402.dpx
a8766ba5d6e1ee854bf7db10c05c7e55  SSJ4_00086403.dpx
733f6564ca442974555a76b91d506cff  SSJ4_00086404.dpx
f6154ddf1d7ae7c8076f08c25c9fe2c3  SSJ4_00086405.dpx
```

Output file3:

```
693d092aba91a6acd2b8d73903fe4f78  SSJ4_00086400.dpx
a8766ba5d6e1ee854bf7db10c05c7e55  SSJ4_00086403.dpx
```